# Stack class in C++

Tags: c++, stack

Please review this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
  Stack() {}
  void push(T x);
  void pop();
  T & top();
  size_t size();
  bool empty();
private:
  std::vector<T> elems;
};

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T x)
{
  elems.push_back(x);
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
  if (elems.size() > 0)
    {
      elems.erase(elems.end() - 1);
    };
}

template <class T>
T & Stack<T>::top()
{
  assert(elems.size() > 0);
  return elems.at(elems.size()-1);
}

template <class T>
size_t Stack<T>::size()
{
  return elems.size();
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty()
{
  return elems.size() == 0 ? true : false;
}

int main()
{

  Stack<int> s;
  s.push(1);
  s.push(2);
  s.push(3);
  s.push(4); 
  s.push(5);

  cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
  cout << "top element: " << s.top() << endl;

  s.pop();
  s.pop();

  cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
  cout << "top element: " << s.top() << endl;
  cout << "empty: " << s.empty() << endl;

  s.pop();
  s.pop();
  s.pop();

  cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
  //cout << "top element: " << s.top() << endl;
  cout << "empty: " << s.empty() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with loki on the size() method.

Maybe assert is not the correct thing here.

```
template <class T>
T & Stack<T>::top()
{
  assert(elems.size() > 0);
  return elems.at(elems.size()-1);
}
```

Maybe an exception would be a better idea.
That way the user has the potential to recover but if they don't specifically check then the application still exits like assert. Also asserts can be turned of. So there is the potential that production code you would get illegal access to the underlying vector.

Why not have the same test on pop() rather than silently failing in this situation?

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
  if (elems.size() > 0)  // This causes a silent fail
                         // But is the same kind of programming bug as top
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the cases I wrote for [your other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/doubly-linked-list-c/4630#4630) are also applicable here. Here's an extra thing:

`return elems.size() == 0 ? true : false;`

The expression `elems.size() == 0` **is** of type bool. What you write is like `if(true) return true; else return false;`.

Comment: While I see no fault in your argument, there are people that I know who _thinks_ that form is easier to follow.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: well, if these people even have problems reading expressions like "1 == 2", I'm curious whether they can write code at all.

Comment: I agree with `return elems.size() == 0;` is more readable but it's more of a coding style argument.

Comment: Coding-styling aspects of this kind is often really bad idea. If someone hires me to write C++ code, I'll write C++ code. If they want me to use a sub-set of C++ (like, no templates) or they require me to write stupidities (like `if(a == true)` instead of `if(a)` in case a is `bool`) that's not C++, that's "let's play the game our teamlead/PM/any-other-idiot-who-is-bored invented".

Comment: @Jeff: Really? You know people who think introducing a ternary operator make the code easier to follow?????

Comment: @Nathanael: Not necessarily _that_, but `if (condition) return true; else return false;`.  Yes, odd I know.

Comment: @Nathanael: it's something with their perception of the world. I'm not a native English speaker, but when I see `x == 0`, I read it as "x is zero", and when I see `return x == 0`, I read it as "tell *them* that x is zero". Ternary in `return x == 0 ? true : false` is like "tell *them* **yes** if x is zero and **no** if it's not". Too many words!

Answer (score 0):

- Methods `size()` and `empty()` should be declared `const`. There also should be overloaded `top() const` method.
- Instead of `elems.at(elems.size()-1)` use `elems.back()`. There is also a method `pop_back()`.
- Don't use `using namespace std`, especially in header files.
- Implementation of these methods is really small, so I would recommend definitions inside class declaration.
- It would be nice to have a constructor that takes expected size of the stack and reserve that amount in `elems`.
- With `assert()` the prerequisite will be unchecked in Release mode – use exception.

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack(size_t size = 0) {
        elems.reserve(size);
    }

    void push(T x) {
        elems.push_back(x);
    }

    void pop() {
        if (!empty()) {
            elems.pop_back();
        }
    }

    T& top() {
        if (empty()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Stack is empty");
        }
        return elems.back();
    }

    T top() const {
        if (empty()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Stack is empty");
        }
        return elems.back();
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return elems.size();
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return size() == 0;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> elems;
};
```